# Nesting with Text.XHtml

Tags: xhtml, haskell, nested

I have the following code to generate a blank html page with a series of divs with id's and classes in Haskell using the [Text.XHtml.Strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xhtml/3000.2.0.1/doc/html/Text-XHtml-Strict.html) library:

```hs
module Main where

import Text.XHtml.Strict
import Text.Printf


page :: Html
page = pHeader +++ pTop +++ pBody +++ pFooter

pHeader :: Html
pHeader = header << thetitle << "Page title" 

pTop :: Html
pTop = (dC "header") << (dI "title") 

pFooter :: Html
pFooter = (dC "footer") << (dI "foottext")

pBody :: Html
pBody = body << (dC "main") << (dI "window") << (dI "content")

dC :: String -> Html
dC x = (thediv noHtml)! [theclass x]

dI :: String -> Html
dI x = (thediv noHtml) ! [identifier x]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    printf $ prettyHtml $ page
```

The functions `dC` and `dI` should make an empty  with a class or id respectively. In the interpreter these functions work fine when concatenating, as in:

```
 printf $ prettyHtmlFragment $ dC "1" +++ dC "2"
<div class="1">
</div>
<div class="2">
</div>
```

But not when I try to nest them using `<<` instead of `+++`, I get an error:

```
<interactive>:1:28:
    Couldn't match expected type `Html -> b'
           against inferred type `Html'
```

This is what I think the cause of the problem in the main part of the code is, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take out the `nohtml` parts, and change the signatures:

```hs
dC :: String -> Html -> Html
dC x = thediv ! [theclass x]

dI :: String -> Html -> Html
dI x = thediv ! [identifier x]
```

The `!` operator can add attributes not only to an `Html` object, but also to a function that returns `Html`. `thediv` is a function that takes `Html` and returns it wrapped in a `<div>` element. By applying `!` to it, you create a function that takes `Html` and wraps a `<div class="…">` (or `id="…"`) around it.

```hs
> :type thediv
thediv :: Html -> Html

> let dC c = thediv ! [theclass c]
> let dI i = thediv ! [identifier i]

> :type dC
dC :: String -> Html -> Html
> :type dI
dI :: String -> Html -> Html

> putStr $ prettyHtmlFragment $ body << dC "main" << dI "window" << dI "content" << "Hi"
<body>
   <div class="main">
      <div id="window">
         <div id="content">
            Hi
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Note that you don't need the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for this, the documentation for this library is hard to come by (except for the hackage documentation) and tutorials are practically nonexistent.

Comment: When looking for doc or examples, remember that the Text.Xhtml package was based on the Text.Html package, and has almost exactly the same usage.

Answer (score 1):

dC and cI can't nest because they're defined to be empty. You need to leave a hole that the nested piece will go into. The hole is expressed by parameterizing it:

```
dC classx child = (thediv child)! [theclass classx] 
dI x y = (thediv y) ! [identifier x]
```

likewise for body:

```
pBody x = body << (dC "main") << (dI "window") << (dI "content" x)
```